# Qt creator C++, setting text of Statuslabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

```
m_pointLabel->setText(tr("Vertices: " .  m_drawingWidget->getPointListSize()));
m_pointLabel->setText(tr("Vertices: " . m_drawingWidget->getLineListSize()));'
```

I am trying to set text, but I am getting the following errors.

```
request for member 'm_drawingWidget' in "Vertices: ", which is of non-class type 'const char [11]'
```

`getPointListSize()` and `getLineListSize()` are returning INT values, so how should I do this text setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is the concatenation operator in PHP, but C++/Qt is *not* PHP.

Use:

```
tr("Vertices: %1").arg(m_drawingWidget->getPointListSize())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're treating a string literal as if it's a class. That's why it's giving the error.

Here is the fix:

```
m_pointLabel->setText(tr("Vertices: %1").arg(m_drawingWidget->getPointListSize()));
                                     //^^^^^^ Note this!
```

Do exactly the same for other `setText` also.